# Why doesn't my show.html.erb load when clicked on in the index?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, show

I am new to Ruby and I was wondering why my show.html.erb does not show in my browser. Instead I get a

uninitialized constant PartiesController error

Here is my code snippet:

Index.html.erb

<%= link_to "Home", welcome_index_path %>

```
<h1>Party Planning 101</h1>
<p>For all your pp needs!</p>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <% @parties.each do |party| %>
      <p><%= link_to party.title, party_path(party.id) %> </p>
      <%end%>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Show.html.erb

```
<h1><%= @party.title %></h1>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'welcome/index'
  root to: 'welcome#index'


  resources :parties
end
```

Am I missing something in routes.rb? I thought resources :parties would take care of all CRUD actions automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is indicating that you don't have a Parties controller, so I'm going to go with that as the source of the problem.

Do you have a file: `app/controllers/parties_controller.rb`?

And is the first line of that file: `class PartiesController < ApplicationController`?

And be sure that spelling/pluralization/etc. are all correct.

Comment: Hey Radshop! Thanks that helped, but I was wondering when do I establish a new controller? Is that only when I want to apply CRUD to the object such as parties?

Comment: Eric - I don't have time to do a full explanation on this right now, but basically the controller is what actually defines what the CRUD should do. The model does what the controller tells it to do, the view displays what the controller passes to it, and the routes just pass the commands. But the controller is the heart of the MVC stack. Find a good reference and read up on it.